# Assigning the contents of a file to an variable

Tags: java, file

I'm currently working on an assignment for my intro programming class and I need to be able to assign the contents of a file to variable. The file contains a text paragraph. I need to be able to eventually count all characters and words in the text file.

What I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountWords {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File inFile = new File("CountWordsTestFile.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);

    String text = input.nextLine();

    int words = 0, cha = text.length(), character = 0;


        System.out.println(text);

    System.out.println("The file contains");
    System.out.println(words + " words");
    System.out.println((cha + 1) + " characters");
        input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder() and then loop through the input and text.append(input.nextLine()) to add all the text to the Stringbuilder.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @vanje he need us to do his homework :) ..

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ReadFile {

    public static void readWords(String filePath) {
        int words = 0;
        int characters = 0;

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(filePath);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").length() == 0) continue;
                characters += line.length();

                line = replaceAllSpecialCharacters(line);
                words += line.split("\\s").length;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Words : " + words);
        System.out.println("Characters : " + characters);


    }

    public static String replaceAllSpecialCharacters(String line) {

        return line.replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]", " ").trim();

    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        readWords("CountWordsTestFile.txt");
    }

}
```

Edit :
Simple Code as your request

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadFile {

    public static void readWords(String filePath) {
      int words=0,characters=0;

        Scanner in= null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(filePath));


        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            //Here you have the value line by line

            String line =in.nextLine();
            //if line is empty or has only spaces continue to the another line
            if(line==null||line.trim().length()==0)continue;

            //add the length for each line to compute characters

            characters+=line.length();



            //replace multiple spaces with one space
           line=line.replaceAll(" +"," ");

            //trim the line to remove spaces 

            line=line.trim();

            //split the line with space to get array of words

            String []wordsArray=line.split("\\s");




            //the length of this array is the # of words in this line

            words+=wordsArray.length;

        }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Words : " + words);
        System.out.println("Characters : " + characters);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        readWords("CountWordsTestFile.txt");
    }



}
```

Comment: Appreciate this but i'm in a BEGINNER programming class. Would you know a way to accomplish the same using maybe an array or some sort of loop(while,for, etc).

Comment: Oh should've mentioned before, everything from the scanner declaration up is mandatory in my final program. So without altering that code and possibly using the scanner object as is... Sorry lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified version of Java program to count characters and words in a file. I assume here that the file is a text file and words in the file are separated by one or more spaces only, not by any delimiter.

```
public class CountWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initializing counter for words and characters in the file
        int words = 0, chars = 0;
        File inFile = new File("CountWordsTestFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                //Read the line and assign it to a string
                String str = scanner.nextLine();
                //Increase the counter for no of characters
                chars = chars + str.length();
                //Split the line by spaces and store in an array
                String[] strArr = str.split("[ ]+");
                //Increase the counter for no of words 
                words = words + strArr.length;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("The file contains");
        System.out.println(words + " words");
        System.out.println(chars + " characters");
    }
}
```

Hope it fits your requirement.

Comment: If you write the full code, you might as well do it right: use try with resources, don't swallow exceptions, and use \s+ in the regex. If you really want the OP to learn something from your answer, explain it, at least so far as to point out the differences between your answer and the OP's attempt.