# Using Arrays to Obtain the Character Count of All Lines Within a File

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to pull elements from a text file, so that I can count the total characters in the file. I wanted to use a `while` loop to add the lengths of each line in the file, and assign it to my character object.  However, I already see a flaw in that approach. I believe that using an array would be the best option, but my knowledge of arrays is insufficient. How can I best achieve this expected behavior using arrays?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountWords {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File inFile = new File("TestFile.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);

    int words = 0, cha = 0, character = 0, temp;

    while(input.hasNext()){

      String text = input.nextLine();

      temp = text.length();

      character = text.length() + temp;
    }

    System.out.println("The file contains");
    System.out.println(words + " words");
    System.out.println(character + " characters");
        input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42589718/6657842

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`character = text.length() + temp;`

with

`character = text.length() + character;`